# useEffect causing render error when attempting to set state in app.js

Tags: reactjs

I've got a useEffect in my app.js file, which attempts to set a 'session' state based upon the response from a function I've got.

```
const App = () => {

 const [session, setSession] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession()
    .then((response) => {
      setSession(response.data.session)
    })

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })

  }, [session])
```

I then pass this state as a prop into my 'Router' component, like so:

```
<Route path="/dashboard/details" element={<PrivateRoute><DashboardDetails session={session}/></PrivateRoute>} />
```

Finally, in my  component, I attempt to access the user's id from the session data, and set it in 'id' state, passing props as a dependency in case the user's id isn't available on the first render:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = props.session.user.id
  setId(id)
}, [props])
```

However, it's returning the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

I know for definite that the session.user.id is the correct path to access it, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to check if the user is undefined or not. use the `?` operator

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = props.session?.user?.id
  if(id) setId(id)
}, [props.session])
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. But why is this the case? Why can't I just check if id exists rather than adding the ? operator?

Comment: because if session object is null you can't access the user. ? will only access the nested properties if object is defined